# Unnest column values in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

What could be a range formula that transforms Table 1 into Table 2?

**Table 1**

|  | A | B |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | foo | X,Y,Z |
| 2 | bar | K,L |

**Table 2**

|  | D | E |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | foo | X |
| 2 | foo | Y |
| 3 | foo | Z |
| 4 | bar | K |
| 5 | bar | L |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Transform Delimited Data

- Note the `1` in `TEXTSPLIT`'s `INDEX`. It took me ages to figure it out.

```
=LET(aData,B2:B3,sData,C2:C3,Delimiter,",",
    Result,DROP(REDUCE("",SEQUENCE(ROWS(aData)),LAMBDA(rRes,rRow,
        LET(Split,TEXTSPLIT(INDEX(sData,rRow,1),,Delimiter),
    VSTACK(rRes,HSTACK(INDEX(aData,SEQUENCE(ROWS(Split),,rRow,0)),Split))))),1),
HSTACK(SEQUENCE(ROWS(Result)),Result))
```

Comment: You are a true master, sir. Thank you!